# postdoc prospects

Tags: postdocs

I am a postdoc now, it is okay, but I do not really see any prospects (unfortunately haha). How do you get out of the vicious loop of postdocs? How to progress in academia careerwise? Great totally new questions. I am tired of the uncertainty and I do not want to do an infinite number of temporary postdocs.

I am not a citizen of the countries, where I work. That puts additional stress on me because basically just living here depends on my temporary positions and I never know what's next (well nobody does, but they can at least try to predict with  a certain confidence). How do people evolve to professors, not in their homeland?  Leaving aside very-very smart and successful researchers, not one of them hah. I think I am quite average, but I am also hard-working and not a complete dum-dum luckily.

Are there any prospects for me to have a stable position in any future? I am a bioengineer with engineering/applied math background if it matters. However, my PhD and current research topics are quite specific; not so easy to transfer to industry (maybe to a junior position only). Also, not if it actually matters, but I am being paid same as PhD students, which does not help with my already desperate vibes (probably it is my fault anyway since I did not negotiate my salary in the first place, agreeable females in action).

I am having a bit of an existential whining crisis here, even though my current university and collegues are nice, just the uncertainty is killing me. Let me know if you had something similar and then everything magically worked out for you out of nowhere:)

Comment: It is certainly a wretched time to be trying to realistically visualize the future... Possibly just being conscientious and _waiting_ is a sane strategy? Dunno.

Comment: Build a track record (publications, grants) that makes you employable in a tenure-track position. The required kind of track record, you can find out by looking at CVs of people who recently got hired in that kind of job. If you don't see yourself being able to build such track record, then you're well-advised to leave academia sooner better than later.

Answer (score 2):

I am in a sort of similar position, I have just managed to get my foot in the door (although in my homeland, so can't help with that side). The truth is you will have to write a *lot* of applications, and even more once you have a position. I wouldn't be afraid of working in industry for a bit either, those links can be vital and set you apart when applying for positions - who knows, you may enjoy working in industry more! Even just talking to people in your current network about your research ideas and seeing where that leads may be useful. There are also websites like euraxess which may give you some idea of positions you can apply for (in europe) and what they need.

Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

You, like many aspiring academics are in a holding pattern now. That is understandable due to economic and health reasons as well as an overabundance of people graduating in some fields. Your solution is to do post-docs. That may be viable, if you are comfortable with it, but there are other possibilities.

You need to be applying to a lot of potential positions, but post-doc and regular faculty. But it you restrict your applications to a narrow segment of academia (say R1 institutions) you will have less of a chance of being able to build a career. In the US, for example, there are a large number of Liberal Arts Colleges that do a fine job of educating students, but where research is less important (and often poorly supported). That isn't always true, of course.

But, you don't need to treat such a position as a 'lower level' one if the environment is good. You can use it to build a career and move back into research later if you make the right moves. Those include keeping active and building a circle of collaborators, perhaps outside the local college. That is easier if you are in a place with a lot of nearby universities, of course, but the internet enables things that weren't possible in the past.

Cast a wide net. Find something interesting to do and plan a longer term strategy.